# Unable to get records from multiparent object

Tags: query, relationships

I am unable to get records from objects which has relationship like the following.

We already knew that Account and contact have relationship where as Account is parent. I created a child for contact and the object name is Product. There is no any relationship between Account and Product.

But now, i want to get records of Contact and Account from Product which means Product is return type.

`SELECT id, name, Product__c.contact__r.lastname, Product__c.contact__r.accountId from Product__c`

By using the Above query, i can able to get product id and name, contact name and account id.

**But How to get account name and phone(remaining fields) along with the Account id.**

Please help me in this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below SOQL you don't need to put the `Product__c.Contact__r.lastname` just put it as `Contact__r.lastName` OR `Contact.Lastname` and is `Contact__c` your custom object I think it should be the standard Object so try both the SOQL given below.

```
SELECT id, name, Contact__r.lastname, Contact__r.account.id,Contact__r.account.Name,Contact__r.account.Phone from Product__c
```

OR

```
SELECT id, name, Contact.lastname, Contact.account.id, Contact__r.account.Name,Contact__r.account.Phone from Product__c
```

Comment: Its my fault. i didn't explain my question completely. Please see my updated question.
and please respond to it.

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: Before posting this question I also tried with `Contact__r.account.Name`, but its showing output like `[object Object]`.

Comment: Where are you executing this SOQL?

Comment: So that's fine it's a limitation of dev console. You can try the same SOQL query on Workbench

Comment: could you respond to me again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51430/discussion-between-ananth-and-rcs).